# How to get uniq rows from duplicate records in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, inner-join

I want to get the fastest quotaBasedService rows from table for each bucket_type. packageSpeed value is in the additionalQuota table with package_id and other fields are in the quotaBased table.

```
SELECT
      q.ID,
      q.SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER,
      q.BUCKET_TYPE,
      MAX(CASE WHEN ext.PACKAGE_SPEED = 0 THEN 999999 ELSE ext.PACKAGE_SPEED END) AS PACKAGE_SPEED
    FROM PIMS_QUOTA_BASED_SERVICE q
      INNER JOIN PIMS_ADDITIONAL_QUOTA_PACKAGE ext ON ext.PACKAGE_ID = q.ADDITIONAL_QUOTA_PACKAGE_ID
    WHERE q.PERIOD = '201810' AND q.BUCKET_TYPE IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      q.SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER,
      q.BUCKET_TYPE,
      q.ID
    ORDER BY SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER, BUCKET_TYPE, PACKAGE_SPEED DESC
```

here is the sql result
quotaBasedId, subs_identifier, bucket_type, speed

```
108337,subscriber1@domain,Extra,999999
108345,subscriber1@domain,Extra,5120
108334,subscriber1@domain,Extra1,999999
108342,subscriber1@domain,Extra1,5120
108336,subscriber1@domain,Extra2,999999
108344,subscriber1@domain,Extra2,5120
108335,subscriber1@domain,Extra4,999999
108343,subscriber1@domain,Extra4,5120
108253,subscriber2@domain,Extra,999999
108261,subscriber2@domain,Extra,5120
108250,subscriber2@domain,Extra1,999999
108258,subscriber2@domain,Extra1,5120
108252,subscriber2@domain,Extra2,999999
108260,subscriber2@domain,Extra2,5120
108251,subscriber2@domain,Extra4,999999
108259,subscriber2@domain,Extra4,5120
```

my expectation is here

```
108337,subscriber1@domain,Extra,999999
108334,subscriber1@domain,Extra1,999999
108336,subscriber1@domain,Extra2,999999
108335,subscriber1@domain,Extra4,999999
108253,subscriber2@domain,Extra,999999
108250,subscriber2@domain,Extra1,999999
108252,subscriber2@domain,Extra2,999999
108251,subscriber2@domain,Extra4,999999
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or set MAX ID so, you wil get the ID too

```
SELECT
      MAX(q.ID),
      q.SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER,
      q.BUCKET_TYPE,
      MAX(CASE WHEN ext.PACKAGE_SPEED = 0 THEN 999999 ELSE ext.PACKAGE_SPEED END) AS PACKAGE_SPEED
    FROM PIMS_QUOTA_BASED_SERVICE q
      INNER JOIN PIMS_ADDITIONAL_QUOTA_PACKAGE ext ON ext.PACKAGE_ID = q.ADDITIONAL_QUOTA_PACKAGE_ID
    WHERE q.PERIOD = '201810' AND q.BUCKET_TYPE IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      q.SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER,
      q.BUCKET_TYPE,
    ORDER BY SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER, BUCKET_TYPE, PACKAGE_SPEED DESC
```

Comment: Good bless you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove `id` from the `group by` and `select`:

```
SELECT q.SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER, q.BUCKET_TYPE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ext.PACKAGE_SPEED = 0 THEN 999999 ELSE ext.PACKAGE_SPEED END) AS PACKAGE_SPEED
FROM PIMS_QUOTA_BASED_SERVICE q INNER JOIN
     PIMS_ADDITIONAL_QUOTA_PACKAGE ext
     ON ext.PACKAGE_ID = q.ADDITIONAL_QUOTA_PACKAGE_ID
WHERE q.PERIOD = '201810' AND q.BUCKET_TYPE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY q.SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER, q.BUCKET_TYPE
ORDER BY SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER, BUCKET_TYPE;
```

If you want the `id`, then you need an aggregation function, probably `MIN()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use `q.ID` in `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT q.SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER, q.BUCKET_TYPE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ext.PACKAGE_SPEED = 0 THEN 999999 ELSE ext.PACKAGE_SPEED END) AS PACKAGE_SPEED
FROM PIMS_QUOTA_BASED_SERVICE q INNER JOIN
     PIMS_ADDITIONAL_QUOTA_PACKAGE ext
     ON ext.PACKAGE_ID = q.ADDITIONAL_QUOTA_PACKAGE_ID
WHERE q.PERIOD = '201810' AND q.BUCKET_TYPE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY q.SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER, q.BUCKET_TYPE
ORDER BY SUBSCRIBER_IDENTIFIER, BUCKET_TYPE;
```

If you want the `q.ID` then aggregate it with using `min()/max()` :